# Sonic Pi doesn't turn on

Tags: software-installation, music

I've recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS in my old laptop, and the very first program I installed was sonic-pi. I tried installing it using the "Ubuntu Software" program. After installation, I clicked on sonic-pi, but wouldn't turn on. I even tried uninstalling it and installing using the terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install sonic-pi
```

but even after doing this, the title screen would show up, but nothing else afterwards. Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is there anything in the system logs that points to the issue? A missing library or unsupported dependency version?

Comment: Try starting the executable (probably `sonic-pi`) from a terminal and see what it complains about.

Comment: Hi @Matigo
When I execute it on terminal, the only significant message I get is this:

"libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile"

What does this mean?

Comment: Hi @Sebastian, I tried on the terminal like you said, and it showed me the message above.

Comment: The iCCP warning is saying that one of the `.png` files used by the application has an issue. You’ll need to find it in the sonic-pi source directory and convert it with: `convert {filename} -strip {filename}`. The `filename` bit should be changed to have the actual file …

Comment: Hey @Matigo So I decided to try looking for a png file, couldn't find any png files.... I even searched with 'locate *.png | grep /usr/share/sonic-pi/' but got nothing... Any other ways to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Was going to comment, but don't have enough reputation.

The `libpng warning:` is likely a red herring, I don't think that would cause sonic-pi to not load.

If you ran it from the terminal, sonic-pi should output more detailed logs in `$HOME/.sonic-pi/log`. For example, `tail $HOME/.sonic-pi/log/server-errors.log` for me shows:

```
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
```

I haven't tried it, but you could be running into similar issues, and I've seen https://github.com/sonic-pi-net/sonic-pi/issues/2341#issuecomment-628016039 suggested as a fix.